# Fst calculation from VCF files

Tags: phylogenetics, sequence-alignment, vcf, fst

I have four vcf files, `SNPs_s1.vcf`, `SNPs_s2.vcf`, `SNPs_s3.vcf`, and `SNPs_s4.vcf`, which contain information about SNPs. These vcf files were obtained by using the following methods: the initial input files were short-paired reads

1. I did mapping with minimap2

   ```
   ./minimap2 -ax sr ref.fa read1.fq.gz read2.fq.gz > aln.sam
   ```
2. converted to bam file

   ```
   samtools view -Sb aln.sam > aln.bam
   ```
3. Sorted the bam file

   ```
   samtools sort aln.bam > aln_sorted.bam
   ```
4. created an index file

   ```
   samtools index aln_sorted.bam
   ```
5. created an index file of reference

   ```
   samtools faidx ref.fa
   ```
6. extracted the raw variants using freebayes

   ```
   freebayes -f ref.fa aln_sorted.bam > out_var_s1.vcf
   ```
7. extracted SNPs using vcf tools

   ```
   vcftools --vcf out_var_s1.vcf --remove-indels --recode \
      --recode-INFO-all --out SNPs_s1.vcf
   ```

I would like to calculate the fixation index (Fst) between `SNPs_s1.vcf` and `SNPs_s2.vcf`, `SNPs_s1.vcf` and `SNPs_s3.vcf` etc. I attempted to calculate Fst using `bcftools`, but I have to provide the id list. I tried the code below for that.

```
bcftools query -l snps_s1.vcf
```

The output was "unknown".

How do I calculate Fst using the above vcf files? Your suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more about Fst, and why you need to calculate it? I'm used to Fst being interpreted as a population statistic, and it doesn't [currently] make sense to me to calculate it for only a few individuals.

Comment: @gringer I would like to use Fst to find the genetic diversity between populations. Which method is better for few individuals?

Comment: Who is asking you to calculate Fst, and why? If you're doing population genetics, you need populations. A few individuals do not make a population, unless it's kākāpō or kakī, or some other similarly endangered species.

Comment: The first issue is easy, the name of your sample in your `snps_s1.vcf` is set to `unknown`. You can fix that bit with `sed -i '/^#CHROM/s/unknown/sample1/' snps_s1.vcf`. But gringer's points are the main issue. What are you really trying to do here with only 4 individuals?